# React js add middleware to redirect to login when axios response is 401

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react js :
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-router": "^5.2.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
I want to add a middleware in my react js code to redirect to the login page when the response from axios on the front end side is 401.
Please any help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following;

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
        return response;
    }, (error) => { // Anything except 2XX goes to here
        const status = error.response?.status || 500;
        if (status === 401) {
             window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/sign-in"
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(error); // Delegate error to calling side
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes , I already trying to use axios.interceptors but the problem was in how can i push to login page : The code that you give me return :  Failed to launch 'localhost:3000/sign-in' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.

Comment: Did you try giving a scheme like 'http' or 'https' before url? E.g. {http}://localhost:3000/sign-in

Comment: I had to put {} because StackOverflow converts it to link directly by the way e.g.  http://localhost:3000/sign-in

Comment: yes ,It's work with http//, have any idea how can I get the url from current path , because i have different adress url for prod and dev environment : i want to do something  like that window.location = currentuRL/sign-in

Comment: I've edited my response  window.location.protocol gives the current protocol/scheme like http: or https:, window.location.host gives current host e.g. stackoverflow.com or my-test-environment.com and last path is your login url.

Comment: Yes, it's works .Thank you so much for your time and answer.